# How do I decompress a folder of files that I accidently saved as foldername.gz instead of foldername.tar.gz

Tags: tar, data-recovery, gzip

I'm not sure how I did this. I had to wipe my dedicated server and start again, so I backed up everything to a remote VPS first; during this process, I compressed a folder full of other folders as foldername.gz instead of using tar, so when I extract it now it extracts as a single file  and not a folder full of folders.
I tried renaming to foldername.tar.gz but when extracting it gives me:

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

When I use `file foldername.gz` it gives me:

`foldername.gz: gzip compressed data, was "2a863233-fac4-4611-8bbd-76416e58e5d4.dat", last modified: Thu Dec  9 10:36:04 2021, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 2629632`

Edit, this is what `file -z foldername.gz` gives:
`foldername.gz: gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT) (gzip compressed data, was "2a863233-fac4-4611-8bbd-76416e58e5d4.dat", last modified: Thu Dec  9 10:36:04 2021, from Unix)`

Comment: How did you compress your folder?

Comment: I cant remember, and since my dedicated is now wiped I cant check history! Im assuming as its .gz I somehow compressed it using just gzip somehow? is it possible to gzip with -r?

Comment: Do you have any idea what piece of software you used to make `foldername.gz`

Comment: @roaima It's a lucky find of mine, but I was *just* wondering the same and am going trhough https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/src/compress.c

Comment: https://github.com/file/file/commit/2e2a77317e19790a5977b4f3cb07030948d5bd1c#diff-8902657c461abb4cfe748c02193189c70f980d3deb45455ef40a8d8b45dfcad2 , so 1991 ?!?!

Comment: https://github.com/file/file/blame/master/src/file.c look for `case 'z':`. 22 years ago

Comment: hm, that implies either `file -z` has a bug (looks like it, for me, there's a difference between `-z` and without `-z`: `file rand.gz`: ```rand.gz: gzip compressed data, was …```, `file -z rand.gz`: ```rand.gz: data (gzip compressed data, was …```), or this is really something `file` doesn't know. Well. Uncompress it (`unpigz -k foldername.gz`, or `gunzip -k foldername.gz`, depending on what you've got installled), try running `file foldername`, see if that is more enlightening. If not, try `binwalk`.

Comment: GodsDead, it looks like the file was compressed and then recompressed. Does `zcat foldername.gz | zcat | file -` return anything sane?

Comment: @roaima oh I didn't consider Matryoshka gzip...

Comment: @roaima `/dev/stdin: PCX ver. 2.5 image data bounding box [3840, 30024] - [29810, 31042], 110 planes each of 3-bit 26964 x 25965 dpi, uncompressed`

I dont remember compressing it twice! But I must have been extremely tired to have done this in the first place, so its possible. I have no idea what this output means.

Comment: we've made progress! stupid question, does PCX seem to make sense to you?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have no idea what PCX is.. sorry

Comment: How big is the foldername.gz file? I think I've got an explanation (if not yet a solution)

Comment: @roaima its 1.6gb compressed, but when I uncompress it into the one file its 4.7gb

Comment: GodsDead you may want to look at this solution for a different question - [Un-concatenate gzipped file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/688060/100397). It looks like it may be exactly what you need(ed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Un-concatenate gzipped file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687900/un-concatenate-gzipped-file)

Answer (score 5):

I would surmise that unfortunately you've not got an archive, compressed or otherwise, of your files.

So what have you got? It looks like you have a concatenation of all the files in the folder, with each one individually compressed:

```
gzip -c * > all_files.gz    # DO NOT DO THIS
```

If you were to uncompress this you would have the equivalent of having done this:

```
cat * > all_files           # OR THIS
```

Not very helpful, as there are no archive markers between files. For text files, you can painstakingly go through the resulting `all_files` file and chop out the relevant parts as files. But as there are no file names or other metadata recorded for each one it's going to be fiddly. Especially as you're talking about a multi-gigibyte file.

In hindsight, what you should have done is something like this, which would have archived the collection of files, compressed it, and written the result to a tarball:

```
tar czf all_files.tgz *
```

There is no easy solution to the recovery of files in your current situation, and possibly no solution at all.

I'd suggest trying some of the undelete tools ([binwalk](http://manpages.org/binwalk), [testdisk](http://manpages.org/testdisk), [photorec](http://manpages.org/photorec), etc.) to see if they have options that might help. Otherwise it might be a case of trying `file` at each byte offset to see if it identifies items for you. You can then use the successful offsets to split out the data into the constituent files. But again, you'll not have filenames or other metadata because that was never saved with the original data.

Good luck

Comment: yeah, *heuristics* is what is left to help here. I'll suggest "binwalk" again, which is not that bad about extracting at least those common file types that have an unmistakeable header and their own length information.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you. Added

Comment: Ah nuts. I still don't even know how I was able to compress a folder as though it was a single file. Luckily I have parts of it in an off site backup, just not as new and not containing all files, there's thousands and thousands of files in this.
Thank you for putting this to rest for me, so now I can figure out what to do from here!